# Read file of any extension using python

Tags: python, file, encoding

I am trying to read contents of various file. Some of those files can be docx extension or pdf or xlsx extension as well.

I tried to use this code

```
for path in paths:
    print(open(path, "r", encoding="utf8").read())
```

but it gave me following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-db6ea654fe14> in <module>
      1 for path in paths:
----> 2     print(open(path, "r", encoding="utf8").read())

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 16: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Only text files encoded as UTF-8 can be decoded as UTF-8.  Binary formats like PDF are not text files, so they must be opened in binary mode ('rb').

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a one liner to read and expose functionality for any type of file extension. You will need to handle each extension accordingly

There are libraries that can help you read certain file formats, so I suggest you use them.

```
import PyPDF2
 
for path in paths:
    if path.endswith(".pdf"):
        with open(path,'rb') as pdf_file:
            pdf_read_obj = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
            print(pdf_read_obj.read()) # This is pseudo code

    elif path.endswith(".docx"):
        # handle doc case
    elif path.endsith("xlsx"):
        # handle excel case
    else: # Default to this case
        try:
            print(open(path, "r", encoding="utf8").read())
        except:
            print(f"Could not read file {path}")
```